# Android volley working with ipv6 internet connection NetSender: Transmitting Exception SSL handshake timed out

Tags: android, android-volley, ipv6

When I connect my device to ipv6 internet connection my volley throws the following exception.

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to
>   nexus-websocket-b.intercom.io/34.235.250.191 (port 443) after 20000ms:
>   isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

It works fine with ipv4 connection and also sometimes it was working but most of the times it throws the following exception in ipv6 connection.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io/54.81.152.198 (port 443) after 20000ms 
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)  
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)  
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   
   at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:47)  
   at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke(Delegator.java:39)
   at com.splunk.mint.network.socket.MonitoringSocketImpl.connect(MonitoringSocketImpl.java:179) 
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)   
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:69) 
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158) 
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)   
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)   
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)   
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125) 
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)   
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)  
   at io.intercom.okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)  
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)  
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)  
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```